# Google OAuth 2: response_type error on token request

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to return an OAuth 2 response code for an OAuth response token. However, my request returns the following error which has zero results in google. I tried changing `response_type` to "token" instead of "code" but that didn't work either.

> OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: response_type

Request Details:

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
client_secret=_____
response_type=code
grant_type=authorization_code
redirect_uri=http://localhost/folder/
client_id=____.apps.googleusercontent.com
code=_____
```

I'm sending this second-step payload to `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`

**What is wrong with my request?**

### Edit

I just realized that there is the `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` URL that should be used for this request. However, changing to that URL now gives:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 27 Jul 2012 22:44:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE

{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

### Edit 2

Removing the `response_type` and changing the URL like above solved this.

Comment: Damn, typing with the smartphone takes too long ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After receiving the authorization code you have to ask '/o/oauth2/token' for the access token. This request takes no 'scope' and no 'response_type'  parameters. See the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

After trying out a couple of methods, the required parameters to make the OAUTH2 call are 
redirect_uri, response_type, scope, client_id. I kept on debugging the oauth call based on the error report I received.