# Google oauth java client to get an access token fails with “400 Bad Request { ”error“ : ”invalid_request“ }”

Tags: java, jsp, rest, google-oauth

This question is in in follow up to my previous question

[Google oauth java client to get an access token fails with "400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_request" }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638758/google-oauth-java-client-to-get-an-access-token-fails-with-400-bad-request-e/13812612#13812612)

I dived into JAVA APIs to solve the problem of exchanging code for an authToken in google's oAuth API but couldn't figure out an answer. Thus I went ahead with a very simplistic route.

I created following JSPs

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=https://gdata.youtube.com/&
redirect_uri=<%=URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:8080/BroadCastr/step2.jsp","UTF-8")%>&
response_type=code&
client_id=X985XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=force">Connect google account</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page presented me with a simple link "Connect google account" which brought me successfully to googles page where I had to "Allow" my app to access youtube on my behalf

In step2.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="frm" method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<%=URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("code"),"UTF-8")%>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="client_secret" value="XXXXxxxxXXXXXX"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="<%=URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:8080/BroadCastr/step3.jsp","UTF-8")%>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value=""/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById("frm").submit();
</script>
```

But finally step2.jsp submits itself to google's server all I get is following unhelpful JSON

```
{
"error": "invalid_request"
}
```

I will really appreciate any help on this one.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post request you send to google? some fiddler capture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While making a POST to the access token end-point, the required parameters should NOT be url-encoded (atleast to the google APIs).

Here, the `redirect_uri` parameter is encoded and hence, it is not the same as the one used at the time of the client registration resulting in `invalid_request`.

Based on the above JSP code, if the `redirect_uri` parameter is fixed, the token server response might result in `invalid_grant`, as the `code` is also being encoded. Usually, google issues an authorization code, which is not url friendly.

Removing the encoding for `code` and `redirect_uri` parameter above should result in a server response containing an access token.

Comment: You were right, not encoding the URI solved the issue partly. Now I am getting "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch" !! I made sure that http://localhost:8080/BroadCastr/step3.jsp is configured in Google API Access Console

Comment: Well you were right, I fixed the last issue by redircting to step2.jsp